# phpexcel style and format with createReader('HTML')

Tags: phpexcel

I'm creating a xlsx file from a html table like this:

```
$tmpfile = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html' );
file_put_contents($tmpfile, utf8_decode( $tablahtml2paraexcel ));

$excelHTMLReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $phpExcelObjectTemp2);

$objWorkSheetBase = $phpExcelObjectTemp2->getSheet();
$objWorkSheetBase->setTitle('Empresas Mayor Contratacion');

$phpExcelObject->addSheet($objWorkSheetBase);
```

But I need to add style and formating to the cells created on the xlsx, like bold, center, vertical alignment, etc. I know how to do it when you build the entire xlsx (2007) cell by cell:

```
$styleBold = array('font' => array('bold' => true));
$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->applyFromArray($styleBold);
```

but don't know how to do it from a html table.

Answer (score 0):

You do it in exactly the same way as when you build the entire xlsx (2007) cell by cell... those style methods work on any `PHPExcel` object, and it doesn't matter whether that object was created by loading an `xlsx` file, a `csv` file, an `html` file, or by creating a new PHPExcel object using `new`. Once the `PHPExcel` object has been created, then it's simply a `PHPExcel` object, with all the methods available to a `PHPExcel` object.

Comment: I can't get it. I'm trying something like: $styleArray = array('font'  => array('bold' => true));$tmpfile = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html' ); file_put_contents($tmpfile, utf8_decode( $tablahtml1paraexcel ) );$excelHTMLReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');$excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $phpExcelObjectTemp1);$objWorkSheetBase = $phpExcelObjectTemp1->getSheet();$objWorkSheetBase->setTitle('Contratacion Energia tiempo');$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);$phpExcelObject->addSheet($objWorkSheetBase); unlink($tmpfile);

Comment: Well there's no reason why it shouldn't work, though your don't show how you create `$phpExcelObjectTemp1` (why don't you simply use `load()` or are you tying to add to an existing file? And you don't show the `save()`, but there's no obvious reason why it shouldn't work.... what's actually happening? Does the load/save work correctly, and it fails too apply the style? Or is it failing on the load or the save?

Comment: This is the code that I'm using: http://ideone.com/i6p59D (it's just the main code, not the entire php file, I'm using Symfony2 by the way but that doesnt matter)

Comment: Looks to me like you create a new PHPExcel object (`$phpExcelObject`); set some properties; remove the only worksheet; then try to apply a style to a worksheet, when there isn't  worksheet there any more! And only then add the worksheet you've loaded from the HTML file.... I'm surprised it doesn't actually error when you try to set the worksheet style at a point where `$phpExcelObject` has no worksheet